# How to implement websocket for auctioning website?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have number of products listed in my site. Each product is identified by its unique URL for eg. product/1/one or product/1/two. When a client opens a product details page and starting bidding, it has to reflect to all the clients opening the same product or page.

I have chosen socket.io to implement websockets but I am unsure how to implement websocket on product or page basis.

Comment: When you chose socket.io, what did you base you decision on? any code you saw? tutorial? official documentation? a friend recommended? All of these will be great places to look for help.

Comment: Sorry for the not so clear question. I solved it by using room concept, where each auction is a room.

Answer (score 0):

My question was not clearly stated since I were a beginner in Socket.IO.

I solved it by using room concept. When a user loads a auction page for product 1, she will join a room identified by the auction id. Hence, all the updates will be broadcasted to all of the users who joined this room.